# No WiFi adapter found (Ubuntu 18.04; Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565/AR9565; Acer Aspire E5-573G)

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, acer, atheros

I am a   Ubuntu user having some problems.
 I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 (the WiFi works fine there) and after the installation was done and I tried to connect to my WiFi (in the settings of course), it said:  `No WiFi adapter found`.
I've spent a day searching for a solution, but nothing worked out. So I have finally decided to ask a question here.
I have no experience with Linux, I am a newbie. I don't really know what info to add, so please say what commands I have to type in the terminal.

```
$ lspci -knn |grep -i -A2 net   
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:098a]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e091]
    Kernel modules: ath9k

$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ dmesg | grep ath
[   16.387522] ath9k 0000:03:00.0: PCI INT A: not connected
[   16.387578] ath9k 0000:03:00.0: request_irq failed
[   16.387600] ath9k: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -107
```

Comment: Done! I hope it doesn't look messy

Comment: give a try `sudo modprobe -v ath9k`

Comment: sudo modprobe -v ath9k gives no output

Comment: How about: `dmesg | grep ath` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: error -107 (ive learned how to format wow)

Comment: "ath9k: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -107" Please see posts #42 and 43 here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390788 Is your BIOS fully updated?

Comment: In   BIOS set IRQs   to auto-select.

Comment: YES! I'VE  DONE IT! I am writing this with my wifi on :) Thank you so much chili555. I have upgraded from 1.25 to 1.37 without any problems (i was pretty nervous while updating the bios). I can finally enjoy ubuntu without any problems

Comment: I knew you were an expert and that i could count on you

Comment: How do I mark this as solved now?

Comment: Post your solution as answer!

Comment: @chili555 Your advice seems to have helped. Wouldn’t you like to post an answer?